# Updating a form control when a process ends

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, asynchronous

I wish to launch multiple processes in parallel when a user clicks a button on a form, and as each completes, update a list-box on the same form.

The [`Process.Exited`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.100).aspx) event seems to be my friend here (remembering to set the `EnableRaisingEvents` property). I assumed I would have to use delegates and [`Control.Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.100).aspx) to update the control, but then I noticed the [`Process.SyncronizingObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.synchronizingobject(v=vs.100).aspx) property.

Their example doesn't actually show the form/control being modified when the event is fired so I wanted to make sure I understood correctly.

If I set `Process.SyncronizingObject` to my `Form` does that mean that my `Process.Exited` event handler method can *directly* modify the form, and any child controls?

So in this way I can run up a bunch of processes in a simple `for` loop, which will run in parallel, and update my GUI as each completes, without *any* need for delegates, locking, etc?

Comment: Seems incredibly easy to test yourself.

Comment: Not really. How do I know from a quick test that it's correct, and couldn't cause infrequent hard-to-track threading bugs? Lots of bad ways of doing this will work in a quick test!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much clearer it can be said:
*[from msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.synchronizingobject(v=vs.100).aspx)*

> When the Exited event is handled by a visual Windows Forms component,
>   such as a Button, accessing the component through the system thread
>   pool might not work, or might result in an exception. Avoid this by
>   setting SynchronizingObject to a Windows Forms component, which causes
>   the methods handling the Exited event to be called on the *same thread
>   on which the component was created*.

Comment: I don't know what "the Exited event is handled by a visual Windows Forms component" means, strictly. A `Button` cannot handle `Process.Exited`. I assume they mean "when a component is altered by an Exited event..." but hence the clarification. And when would you set `SynchronizingObject` to the Form, and when to a specific control?

Comment: You are correct.  Their wording could be a little more precise.  Personally I would never set the SynchonizationObject to anything other than a form.  But if for some *absolutely parallel-dimension bat-crap crazy reason* you create a control on a thread that is not the UI thread, AND that control needs to be updated from the Exited event, then set that control as the Sync object.